# How do I stop Sublime Text 3 from being the Git editor on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, git, sublime-text-3

On Windows 8, I've configured gvim as my Git editor in ~\.gitconfig:

```
[core]
editor = gvim -f -n
```

Still, Sublime Text 3 opens as the editor when I invoke `git commit`. How do I stop Sublime from overriding my chosen Git editor (gvim)?